# Garage Door Part?

Tags: garage-door

[image: Garage door bracket]

I'm having trouble finding this piece. The garage door is an old manual door for a shed that was missing the bracket when we got the home.

Without this bracket, the top left corner of the door hangs open and has to have a wedge propped up against it to keep it closed.

I'm looking for either the name of this piece, where I might find one, or what I could do as a replacement.

Comment: This looks like a serious antique to me, and a funky one at that. Am I right that the bracket is designed to pull the top of the garage door quickly away from the frame as it's being lifted? Quite cool, and I'm not surprised you've had a tough time finding one.

Comment: @DanielGriscom You're right. It slides off of that bolt piece that is stationary with the frame and eventually lays parallel with the frame when fully opened, laying onto that bolt that's on the roller.